# Пространства имён в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Чем объясняется следующее поведение?

```
i = 0
x = []
for i in range(20):
    x.append(i)
print(i)  # 19
```

В случае же сокращённой записи:

```
i = 0
x = []
[i for i in range(20)]
print(i)  # 0
```

В чём концептуальные различия?

Comment: _Включения_ не создают [побочных эффектов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Comment: концептуальные различия в том, что во втором случае вы не присваиваете список переменной, list comprehension у вас работает "в воздух". Как отметил Сергей, в `[i for i ...]`, i - это не глобальная переменная, определенная вами ранее, это placeholder для генерируемого значения.

Comment: Где это описано в стандарте? @strawdog

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

6.2.4. Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries: `However, aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost for clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t “leak” into the enclosing scope.`

Comment: С небольшой преамбулой это можно оформить как ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Я не знаю точный ответ, но очевидно, что так короче. Если вы захотите записывать в x не i, а i^2, то такая запись будет явно короче. Не исключаю, что она и работает быстрее из-за внутренней оптимизации.

```
[i**2 for i in range(20)]
```

Стоит отметить, что во втором случае значение возвращается, а не сохраняется. Многие методы питона так поступают. Т.е. если вы запишите так `x = [i for i in range(20)]` или так `[x.append(i) for i in range(20)]`, то будет идентично. 
Надеюсь, кто нибудь оставит здесь будет более полный и точный ответ:)

Answer (score 0):

С данной формой записи все понятно:

```py
i = 0
x = []
for i in range(20):
    x.append(i)
print(i)  # 19
```

И полный эквивалент через использование [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
x = [i for i in range(20)]
```

И если в этом случае вы выведете `print(i)`, то получите ошибку, поскольку переменная `i` определена только внутри генератора и не релевантна вне данного процесса. Ошибка будет:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Хотел бы еще обратить внимание на то, что в данном случае генератор семантически ничем не будет отличаться от выражения:

```py
x = list(range(20))
```

В чем прелесть двух последних записей? Вы не создаете промежуточных переменных типа `i = 0` и `x = []`, следовательно избавляетесь от побочных эффектов, получаете более лаконичную и понятную запись. Использование `list(iterable)` можно применять везде, где нет условий по итерируемым значениям. В обратном случае используйте `list comprehensions`